# Deleting asset and transform job (Azure Media Services v3)

Tags: .net, azure, video-streaming, video-processing, azure-media-services

What's the best practice for deleting an asset in Azure Media Services?

I'm aware of [Delete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/delete) method. However, I'm wondering what's gonna happen when the asset is still not processed and there is a non-processed transform job submitted. Should I check whether such a transform job exist and [Delete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/jobs/delete) it? Or [Cancel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/jobs/canceljob) it?

Edit:  I want to allow users to delete assets the asset when they upload the wrong video and they realize it after the upload is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the reply based on updated context info. Yes, in this case, if you have to delete an Asset if the wrong video has been uploaded, you can attempt to cancel the Job and delete it. You should anticipate situations where the service errors the Job just before you cancel it.

Comment: Thank, you. So Cancel and then Delete might be the best practice, do I understand it correctly? I've edited my original question with some additional context.